# How to implement CCAvenue payament gateway in Windows 8 App using C# and XAML

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5, ccavenue

I am trying to implement CCAvenue payment gateway in Windows 8 App using C#. I am not able to find how to achieve this. Is there any article related to integrating payment gateway in Windows 8 App?